# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: dict

Tags: python, airflow

I have a sensor task in an Airflow DAG that looks like this:

```
sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
  task_id='wait_for_parent',
  external_dag_id='parent',
  external_task_id='reporting',
  allowed_states=['success'],
  execution_date_fn=get_updated_exec_date,
  dag=dag)
```

The function `get_updated_exec_date` is defined like this:

```
def get_updated_exec_date(execution_date, delta=-1):
  date_next_month=execution_date + relativedelta(months=1)
  start_next_month=date_next_month.replace(day=1)
  return start_next_month + timedelta(days=delta)
```

This works perfectly on Airflow 1.10.6. We're migrating to 1.10.15, and in this environment, the exact same code crashes on the `return` statement with `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: dict`

Is someone able to help please?

Comment: I would assume that the `get_updated_exec_date` is called with the context dictionary which is being assigned to delta (replacing the default value) of -1. Try to change the signature to `get_updated_exec_date(execution_date, delta=-1, **context)`

Comment: What @Elad said. This is called out in the changelog for `1.10.11` (under "Add context to execution_date_fn in ExternalTaskSensor"), which your upgrade from `1.10.6` would catch: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/changelog.html#airflow-1-10-11-2020-07-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow 1.10.11 add [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8702) which Add context to `execution_date_fn` in `ExternalTaskSensor`. So what happens in your code is that the `context` is being passed to `delta` and overwriting the default value of -1. since `context` is of type dict you are experiencing the error.

The fix is to replace the function signature to:

```
def get_updated_exec_date(execution_date, context)
```

Since `delta` is always `-1` just move it inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and what you say makes perfect sense, however when I make the suggested change I still get the same error.

Comment: try get_updated_exec_date(execution_date, delta=-1, context)

Comment: progress! The new error is `AirflowException: execution_date_fn passed 3 args but only allowed up to 2`

Comment: So yeah this is the same issue as described in the review of the PR. It was solved in Airflow 2 https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11922 Try to do `def get_updated_exec_date(execution_date, context)` and extract delta from the context like `context['delta']`

Comment: that gives a keyerror on context, which I understand because it was never declared. delta is ALWAYS -1 in this situation so I have just set it inside the function and it's all working now. Thanks for your help.